# How to display remaining time before user can attempt another log in and query for oldest attempt?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

With my current code, I block user attempts if there are 5 attempts in 10 minutes. It is currently just echoing out the flat interval. How do I display the exact amount of time left before they are able to begin another attempt? Also, how do query the attempts to return the oldest attempt made to compare to NOW()?
I am using timestamp format: 2020-05-03 14:51:41
 Here is the current code:

```
$sql=("SELECT email FROM login_fail where email=? AND `time` > (now() - interval 10 minute)");
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param("s",$_POST['username']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
      if($stmt->num_rows > 4){

        die("Please try again in 10 minutes");
        // Id prefer.... die("Please try again in X minutes / seconds");
       }
     $stmt->bind_result($email);
     $stmt->fetch();
```

Comment: for that you must save the time in the session variable or in the database to check against.

Comment: i do have it saved in the database, thats how i am able to query for the current error

Answer (score 0):

This would calculate the minutes and the seconds and you can bind the results to new variables.

```
$sql=("SELECT email,TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,`time`,NOW()) as timeagain, (TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,`time`,NOW()) Mod 60) timeseconds FROM login_fail where email=? AND `time` > (now() - interval 10 minute) ORDER BY `time`");
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param("s",$_POST['username']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($email,$minute,$seconds);
    $stmt->fetch();
    if($stmt->num_rows > 4){

      die("Please try again in $minute minute(s) and $seconds second(s)");
      // Id prefer.... die("Please try again in X minutes / seconds");
    }
```

**EDIT**
I entered an  Order by  tiemto get the first of all failed emails in the last minute and get the first record, with is the only interesting

Comment: Where's the bit that picks the oldest of the four?

Comment: @Strawberry, its in the WHERE clause based on time > 10 minutes ago.  The original post was looking for a 10-minute maximum for 5 failures.  And not the oldest, but the most recent attempt at logging in.

Comment: but now he wants the oldest to get the 10 ,minute time limit, but we have not the compolete to see what comes next.

Answer (score 0):

to get the latest failure time, just do a MAX()

```
SELECT max( `time` ) as LastLoginAttempt
   from login_fail 
   where email = ? 
     AND `time` > (now() - interval 10 minute)
```

So, of the 4 attempts logged in, you only care about the LATEST time.  If you want to apply the timestamp difference, you could add that too, or just compute on the PHP side from getting the datetime field returned back
Your filter is already by the single employee, so no need to "group by" since it is a single person.

Comment: is this more efficient than doing order by date ASC limit 1?

Comment: @markusman, don't know, and don't think I'd worry if you only have so few records.  Microseconds different?